# GoogleTest Linking Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol, when using ::testing::FLAGS_XXX parameters

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am using the MS Visual Studio 2017 to build a unit test project. I linked the 'gtest.lib' and included the header files. I was not able to compile the project when using the ::testing::FLAGS_xxx line. Unable to figure out how to solve this error or where to look for. I checked that gtest.lib was linked and worked when ::testing::FLAGS_xxx parameters are not used. My issue is similar to https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/2145. Tried this solution but this didn't help.

Code I used.

```
#include "gtest/gtest"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    ::testing::FLAGS_gtest_output = "xml:Reports\\Report.xml"; // when using this line - cannot compile 
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Error I get is:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > testing::FLAGS_gtest_output" (?FLAGS_gtest_output@testing@@3V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by recompiling the Google GTest library by disabling the "BUILD_STATIC_LIB" variable in cmake. This way I was able to build a static library that does not require the .dll's to be deployed along with the unit test executable file (static linking).